Did Jesus do miracles by his own power, by the power of the Holy Spirit, or both?
Acts 10:37-38 NIV

You know what has happened throughout the province of Judea, beginning in Galilee after the baptism that John preached — how God anointed Jesus of Nazareth with the Holy Spirit and power, and how he went around doing good and healing all who were under the power of the devil, because God was with him.

Matthew 8:26-27 NIV

He replied, “You of little faith, why are you so afraid?” Then he got up and rebuked the winds and the waves, and it was completely calm. The men were amazed and asked, “What kind of man is this? Even the winds and the waves obey him!”.

So Jesus's miracles were all made through the power of the Holy Spirit, his own power, or both Jesus and Holy Spirit's power?

This is not really an exegetical question about either of those passages - instead it's a theological question. Theology questions generally belong on the [Christianity.se] site instead, but you would need to specify a denomination/movement whose perspective you are after.

@curiousdannii A problem with transferring Hermeneutic Qs to the Christianity site has occurred with this recent transfer: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/102882/how-do-trinitarians-explain-why-jesus-didnt-mention-the-holy-spirit-in-matthe/102887#102887  It has been attributed to the wrong Dieter. I left you a comment about that in the link above.

I will argue that Jesus performed all His miracles without His own innate power, but only the power of the Father and/or the Holy Spirit.  as evidence for this I cite the following:

Phil 2:5-8 - ... Christ Jesus: Who, existing in the form of God, did not consider equality with God something to be grasped, but emptied Himself, taking the form of a servant, being made in human likeness. And being found in appearance as a man, He humbled Himself and became obedient to death— even death on a cross. [Thus, Jesus put aside His innate divinity to become human and live like a human.]
Heb 4:15 - For we do not have a high priest who is unable to sympathize with our weaknesses, but we have one who was tempted in every way that we are, yet was without sin.
Luke 5:17 - One day Jesus was teaching, and the Pharisees and teachers of the law were sitting there. People had come from Jerusalem and from every village of Galilee and Judea, and the power of the Lord was present for Him to heal the sick.
John 14:12 - Truly, truly, I tell you, whoever believes in Me will also do the works that I am doing. He will do even greater things than these, because I am going to the Father. [That is, Jesus was not using any power, from the father, that is not available to any other disciple/believer in Jesus.]
John 9:3 - Jesus answered, “Neither this man nor his parents sinned, but this happened so that the works of God would be displayed in him.
Acts 2:22 - Men of Israel, listen to this message: Jesus of Nazareth was a man certified by God to you by miracles, wonders, and signs, which God did among you through Him, as you yourselves know.
Matt 4:1 - Then Jesus was led up into the wilderness by the Spirit to be tempted by the devil. [See also Luke 4:1.]
Matt 12:28 - But if I drive out demons by the Spirit of God, then the kingdom of God has come upon you.
Acts 10:38 - how God anointed Jesus of Nazareth with the Holy Spirit and with power, and how Jesus went around doing good and healing all who were oppressed by the devil, because God was with Him.
Heb 2:17 - For this reason He had to be made like His brothers in every way, so that He might become a merciful and faithful high priest in service to God, in order to make atonement for the sins of the people.

Thus, while Jesus had unlimited power, He never used it but, just like us, depended at all times on the Father and the Holy Spirit for guidance and power.  This is further evidence by Jesus frequent use of extended prayer for power and strength.

I would like to add Matthew ch12 v28; "If it is by the Spirit of God that I cast out demons, then the kingdom of God has come upon you" (RSV).

@StephenDisraeli - excellent suggestion.  I will add it.

The OP seems to have drawn a strong converse from the English-language translation of Acts 10:37-38.
he went around doing good and healing... because God was with him.
he went around doing good and healing... only because God was with him.
ὅτι ὁ Θεὸς ἦν μετ’ αὐτοῦ·
Moule (1953) p.147 gives a detailed discussion of ὅτι and the problem of deciding if it's a because or a that and which word the logical connection is being made to. English as the receiving language tends to force either a 'because' or a 'that' which each introducing a distinct type of strong converse.

Applying what Moule says to the OP's passage there are three options and three sorts of converses:-
(Acts 10:38) He διῆλθεν doing good and ἰώμενος all who were καταδυναστευομένους by the devil, ὅτι God was with him. (ESV)
(1) ὅτι+ἰώμενος - Jesus heals because God is with him < per the OP (converse: he can only heal because God is with him)
(2) ὅτι+διῆλθεν - Jesus might be healing because God's with him (converse: and when God isn't around he watches chariot races or chills out and does some hermeneutics!)
(3) ὅτι+καταδυναστευομένους - People might be being oppressed by the devil because God is with Jesus. (converse: that it's only this and not 1 or 2)

The problem with translating ὅτι is that it links to all three - ὅτι has a wider and softer and more encompassing logic than English 'because' or 'that'
διῆλθεν being the main verb carries more of the logical connection than the participles ἰώμενος and εὐεργετῶν. Jesus was healing and doing good because his ministry had commenced. God is with everyone all the time, but ὁ Θεὸς ἦν μετ’ αὐτοῦ refers in particular to the ministry.
καταδυναστευομένους being closest to the ὅτι also carries more of the logical connection. The possessions seem to have been somewhat targeted toward Jesus, e.g. with them already knowing who he was. And καταδυναστευομένους=oppressed is a natural contrast to μετ’ αὐτοῦ - where the devil possesses and cajoles God reinforces and supports.
But my point is just that the strong converse 'only because' can't be drawn from (1) and so the OP's main question doesn't really arise from these two passages.
As Expositor's commentary says "ὁ Θεὸς ἦν μετʼ αὐτοῦ [...] We cannot see in the expression a “low” Christology; St. Peter had first to declare that Jesus was the Christ, and it is not likely that he would have entered upon a further exposition of His Person in his introductory discourse with a Gentile convert; but Acts 10:42-43 below, to say nothing of St. Peter’s public addresses, certainly do not point to a humanitarian Christ."
Perhaps another way of looking at ὅτι is that it's a more ancient sort of thing than because. It doesn't introduce a logical connection so much as supply the listener/reader with a piece of information they needed to make sense of what's just been said.
